# AVAssetExportSession Fails when called by selector

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am trying to export an asset using `AVFoundation`. I have the code for the exportSession setup and it works fine if it is placed in `viewDidLoad()`. However, if I place the logic in a function that is called when a button is pressed, the session fails with an unknown error.

Here is the code I am using:

```
@objc func uploadVideo() {
    guard let url = self.videoUrl else { return }
    var asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

    let compatiblePresets = AVAssetExportSession.exportPresets(compatibleWith: asset)

    if compatiblePresets.contains(AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality) {
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality)
        let outputUrl = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("testing.mp4")
        exportSession?.outputURL = outputUrl
        exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        exportSession?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            guard let status = exportSession?.status else { return }
            switch status {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print(exportSession?.error)
                break
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                break
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
                print("Exported succesfully...")
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When this method is called I get the following error in the console:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x10b41b400 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16979 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16979)
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need to `break` out of your switch cases, in Swift switch cases are exclusive by default and hence they don't fall through to the next case.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks, I am aware. They are there because each case must have at least once executable line. So in this case they are necessary. I just added the print statements.